# Phone system - Virtual PBX

Tags: phone

I'm looking at purchasing an 0845 number for my company. I'm using a company which allows the number to be forwarded to one local number however, i'd like to be able to point this number at a virtual PBX type system so that the number can be configured to call a local number and if it goes unanswered it will ring another.

Also a nice feature would be to have a professional voice welcoming the caller.

Does anyone know if a free/cheap system which would do this?

Or is this easy to setup using some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Grasshopper: http://grasshopper.com/
It isn't free but is an excellent way to set up a professional virtual PBX.

Comment: Thanks but need a UK service

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have paid closer attention to the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it by setting up your own Asterisk server using something like [Trixbox](http://fonality.com/trixbox/) or [PBX in a Flash](http://pbxinaflash.net/). You could have someone record a nice friendly greeting for you too.

Not sure where you are purchasing your 0845 number but I got mine from voip.co.uk (I have used them for about 3 years) and as this will be a VoIP-based number it will tie straight into an Asterisk-based system - the 0845 number should be dirt cheap too and you'll be able to divert it to any other number - I have just setup one that terminates at a SIP/Voip Client on my mobile phone.